# stack run with profiling in haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I tried running

```
$ stack build --profile && stack run myexec --rts-options -p
```

But I get

```
... 
Registering library for mylibrary-0.1.0.1..
Completed 2 action(s).      
myexec: the flag -p requires the program to be built with -prof
...
```

I know I could run

```
$ .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/myexe/myexe +RTS -p
```

But what's the point of `stack run` then? I don't want to have to know the version of cabal and the architecture etc (this all happens in a makefile).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command that you use `stack run` is a convenience command that not only runs the binary, but also builds it prior to that. So when you run `stack build --profile` it compiles you binary with all of the necessary ghc flags, but when you call `stack run` it compiles it again, but now without all of the profiling flags. So there are two way to do it properly:

1. Don't run `stack build`, since it is redundant:

```sh
$ stack --profile run myexec --rts-options -p
```

2. or call the executable directly with `+RTS` flags, but make sure to pass `--profile` to both `stack` invocations, otherwise the `stack exec` will be looking in the wrong place for the binary (namely non-profiling build) and will fail to find it.

```sh
$ stack --profile build
$ stack --profile exec -- myexec +RTS -p
```